# Creating file geodatabases in multiple folders using iterator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, iterator

Software Spec:  ArcMap 10.2.1  Advanced Licence.

I have a single folder, let's call it "Processing".
Inside this folder are 15 empty folders.  Let's call these "Output_1" through to "Output_15". There is nothing else in the "Processing" folder.

I am trying to use ModelBuilder to create an empty file geodatabase inside each Output folder with the same name as the folder.
i.e. in the "Output_1" folder, the file gdb will be called "Output_1.gdb".

I thought this would be very straight forward using an "Iterate Workspace" iterator, where the input is the "Processing" folder.

I could then use the output workspace from the iterator as the file gdb location into the "Create file gdb" tool, and the %Name% from the iterator as the file dgb name.

However, the "Create File GDB" tool won't accept the workspace output from the iterator as the file gdb location.

I have tried changing the iterator settings so that the workspace type it looks for is only folders, but this doesn't fix this issue.

I have also tried changing the input variable (called "Processing") between a "folder" and a "workspace".  This makes no difference.

Is there something fundamental I am missing?  Or is this a bug?

[image]

If I first run just the iterator part of the model, I am then able to connect the "wokspace" output as the input location for the "Create file gdb" tool.  I can then run just the "Create file gdb" tool, but obviously this only runs for the last folder that was read by the iterator.

[image]

Comment: I have solved this using a list and the parse path tool rather than an iterator.  However, it would still be good to know if this can be done with an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by:

1. Specifying that *Workspace* is a **Precondition** to *Create File GDB*
   [image]
2. Using %Name%\%Name% as the File GDB Name, *not* as part of the location 
   [image]

This results in the desired output:

[image]

Comment: Good find! I'll put an image of my solution up as well in case somebody else tries to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it, by using a list variable for the 15 folders as the input.
And the Parse type to return the "Name".

[image]